# Ionic 4 - AlertController: Property 'present' does not exist - Angular?

Tags: ionic-framework, mobile-application, ionic-native, ionic4

I'm setting up a new alert in Ionic 4 - blank type:angular project. 
It's basic alert but I get an error occured running of my project.

## Error

Property 'present' does not exist on type 'Promise'. Did you forget to use 'await'?

My create the same code as in documentation. Links:https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/components/alert/AlertController/

My code:

```
import { AuthenticationService } from './../../services/authentication.service';
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { AlertController, LoadingController, NavController } from 
'@ionic/angular';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-register',
  templateUrl: './register.page.html',
  styleUrls: ['./register.page.scss'],
})
export class RegisterPage implements OnInit {
  createSuccess = false;
  registerCredentials = { email: '', password: '' };

 constructor(
   private nav: NavController,
   private auth: AuthenticationService,
   private alertCtrl: AlertController) { }

 ngOnInit() {
 }

 presentAlert() {
    const alert = this.alertCtrl.create({
    message: 'Low battery',
    subHeader: '10% of battery remaining',
    buttons: ['Dismiss']
   });
   alert.present(); <--- error Property 'present' does not exist on type 'Promise<HTMLIonAlertElement>'. Did you forget to use 'await'?
}
public register() {
this.auth.register(this.registerCredentials).subscribe(success => {
  if (success) {
    this.createSuccess = true;
    this.showPopup('Success', 'Account created.');
  } else {
    this.showPopup('Error', 'Problem creating account.');
  }
},
  error => {
    this.showPopup('Error', error);
  });
}
```

showPopup function that shoulbe be working..

```
showPopup(title, text) {
let alert = this.alertCtrl.create({
  message: title,
  subHeader: text,
  buttons: [
    {
      text: 'OK'
    }
  ]
});
alert.present(); <-- the same error
}
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The documentation you are using refers to `ionic 3`
As you are using **Ionic 4**, you need to refer to the current Ionic 4 [docs](https://beta.ionicframework.com/docs/api/alert/) and [this](https://beta.ionicframework.com/docs/api/alert-controller).

```
this.alertController.create({...})
```

returns promise of the object as the error specifies.

Your code needs to be:

```
 async presentAlert() {
    const alert = await this.alertCtrl.create({
    message: 'Low battery',
    subHeader: '10% of battery remaining',
    buttons: ['Dismiss']
   });
   await alert.present(); 
}
```

Answer (score 9):

Since create method of alert controller return promise that's why you can not use present method directly. What you need to do is "use then" and call present method like below-

```
presentAlert() {
  const alert = this.alertCtrl.create({
  message: 'Low battery',
  subHeader: '10% of battery remaining',
  buttons: ['Dismiss']}).then(alert=> alert.present());
}
```

Hope it will helpful :).

Answer (score 3):

**I have resolved with this solution ..**

Write **`alert.present()`** like this **`(await alert).present()`**

```
async presentAlert() {
    let alert = this.alertCtrl.create({
      subHeader: 'Low battery',
      message: 'This is an alert message.',
      buttons: ['Dismiss']
    });
    (await alert).present();
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to use `async` and `await`. Here is a code sample:

```
 async showAlert () {
  const alert = await this.alertCtrl.create({
    header: 'Alert',
    subHeader: 'Subtitle',
    message: 'This is an alert message.',
    buttons: ['okay']
  });
  await alert.present();
};
```